# Magento : High resolution product image are not displaying on product detail page

Tags: magento-1.8, cache, product-images, permissions

Some product image are not showing on product page. It works fine with low resolution. I don't know what is problem. I have set media folder permission, as well as `resize` and `setQuality` function also set but no luck with this.

It's working on my another server but on live it's return blank page. Working resolution are below please check.

It's working fine for `1160px` width and `624px` height on live but when I upload image with `2331*1247` dimensions, it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

[Follow this tutorial](http://www.classyllama.com/blog/implementing-high-res-images-magentos-native-responsive-theme) to display your high resolution images.

Comment: I have already try this but not work for me